# Why [0] in $(#textbox1)[0].value is used to get scalar value in asp.net control?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, textbox

I am novice to jquery and asp.net. I am using the following coding to retrieve value. Why [0] in $(#textbox1)[0].value is used? is there any alternative way to retrieve value?.

```
$.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "Default.aspx/GetTextData",
                     data: "{}",
                     contentType: "application/json",
                     dataType: "json",
                     success: function(msg) {
                       $("#txtResult")[0].value = msg.d;
                     }
                 });
```

Many Thanks

Comment: you can use `$('#txtResult').val(msg.d)` instead

Comment: Maybe you have many txtResults and you won only the first one.

Comment: @Aristos - You can't have many of them, because you would have ID collisions, you can only have one control with a given ID on a page, or problems occur.

Comment: alternatively you can use `$('#txtResult').val(msg.d)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of your code, it's not actually retrieving value, it's setting:

`$("#txtResult")[0].value = msg.d`

You can use the alternative, jQuery syntax of (as per my comment):

`$('#txtResult').val(msg.d)`

It's required to use `[0]` as the author of that code would like to assign a value to the standard `DOMElement` of the input, as `[0]` is used to get the native `DOMElement` from that jQuery object. Alternatively you can use:

`$('#txtResult').get(0).value = msg.d`

Although the previous way is still preferrable

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `$("#txtResult").val(msg.d)` instead since that's the jQuery function.

The reason for using [0] is to access the DOM-element instead of the jQuery one (eg. you cant run `$("#txtResult")[0].val(msg.d)` since `.val` is a jQuery function)

`$("#txtResult").val(-something-)` actually sets the value (not retrieving as you write in your question).

`$("#txtResult").val()` is the command used for retrieving value from an element.